# EaselJs errors in chrome

Tags: html, html5-canvas, easeljs

Am using Easeljs library. Everthing works fine in firefox and ie9 except in google chrome mouse events wont work and I got this error 
"Uncaught An error has occured. This is most likely due to security restrictions on reading canvas pixel data with local or cross-domain images."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serve your page from a web server.  Do not open the file from disk in chrome.

Comment: oh thank god and i thought i'd have to scrap chrome altogether from the supported client list.

Comment: **`°_°`** I am using my optimization routine: you are on `www.abc.com` and all my static files are on `s1.abc.com`, `s2.abc.com` and `s3.abc.com`. So this would imply that this limitation could apply too whereas it's the *same* root DNS? Watch here, I'm currently trying to use EaselJS: http://www.battlesoop.fr/battleship/ try to click on one of the buttons, you'll get the error. How to deal with it?

Comment: And I'm wondering how will the "big ones" do with their static files based on other domain names (Yahoo, Amazon and Google, not to name them) => http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I've enabled `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` but this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibly working answer is:

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(true, null, true);
```

Since v.0.4.1, here's what they say:

> The crossOrigin flag is already included in the LoadQueue()
>   constructor of v.0.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Just run you Chrome with --reduce-security-for-testing command-line argument. So you can develop your project locally without using web server.